# Why mutable lambda with pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, c++11

I'd like to get my mucky paws on the `operator()` of a lambda function. The following seems up the task:

```
template <typename F>
void bar(F func) {
  void (F ::*pm)();
  pm = &F::operator();
}
```

However, in the following, I need to include the `mutable` keyword. Why is that? Is it possible to above instead declare a pointer to member function, which can target arbitrary lambdas?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  bar([]() mutable {});
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Maybe the lambda's operator is `const`, can you add that to your function pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to 5.1.2 of the N3291 C++0x specification, the lambda's operator() is `const` unless you explicitly declare it `mutable`:

> This function call operator is declared `const` (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda-
>   expression’s parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by `mutable`.

You may be able to do some template metaprogramming magic to detect which is which.

However, it should be noted that, once `func` goes out of scope, you can't use that member pointer anymore. And it is a member pointer, not a function pointer, so you can't convert between the two.

Answer (score 4):

C++0x lambdas are const by default, unlike the rest of the language. Consequently, your member-function variable must be const as well. The following should work:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void bar(F func) {
    typedef void (F::*pm_t)() const;
    pm_t pm = &F::operator();
}
```

Comment: Alas, with `mutable`, no:    `error: cannot convert ‘void (main(int, char**)::<lambda()>::*)()’ to ‘pm_t {aka void (main(int, char**)::<lambda()>::*)()const}’ in initialization`

Comment: @user643722 : With what version of what compiler? [Works just fine with GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/bRQFk).

Comment: Ok, it works without `mutable`, +1, but can I have a pointer to function which can point to either `mutable`, or `const`?

Comment: @user643722 : Sure, use `decltype` instead of your own typedef, so the compiler can deduce the signature of `operator()` on its own. Or are you asking how to determine whether it's `const` or not without using `decltype`?

Comment: @ildjarm: Ah, of course. In fact `auto` can help us too: `auto pp = &F::operator();`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
int x=0;
auto show = [x]() mutable
{
        x++;
};

show();
```

The variable 'x' is being captured **by-value**, and without `mutable`, you cannot modify the local copy of this variable. Specify `mutable` to enable modification of this local copy. For by-value captures, it doesn't matter if value is modified, the original `x` variable won't be modified.